# netcat from ubuntu

Tags: netcat

I'm trying to use netcat to catch kernel printing (netconsole) using `nc -l -u -p 6666`.

But when I use this utility in Ubuntu, it immediately exits.

Trying to figure out why, I see that in the manual page it is described that `-l` & `-p` can't be used together.

The next time I tried to execute it as following.

This time I started to get some reply but then it exits.

```
$ nc -l -u 6666
netconsole: local port 6665
netconsole: local IP 0.0.0.0
netconsole: interface 'eth0'
netconsole: remote port 6666
netconsole: remote IP 10.0.0.1
netconsole: remote ethernet address ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
netconsole: local IP 10.0.0.2
```

Then I get back host prompt, as if netcat existed without printing anything more.

Can someone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@ransh, you're using OpenBSD Netcat, which has a different syntax. I suggest you to change to `netcat-traditional`:

```
sudo update-alternatives -config nc
```

Select the option /bin/nc.traditional. Verify and new version:

```
nc -h
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use *-l* and *-p* yes. Try:

```
sudo nc -u -v -l -p 6666
```

Use *-u* if you're looking for UDP packages.

Comment: Hi Wiliiam, I just tried it now in ubuntu 10.04 but I get the description of nc arguments (as if it contain some error argument). I copy pase exactly what you wrote above. Note that in manual page it is said not to use -l & - together.

Comment: So strange. I tested my command before post the answer. I'm using Debian Wheezy. Can you update your `nc` package? Can you verify your nc version, please?

Comment: I updated it now, but still it is the same result. How can I get the version ?

Comment: from man page:
    -l      Used to specify that nc should listen for an incoming connection
             rather than initiate a connection to a remote host.  It is an
             error to use this option in conjunction with the -p, -s, or -z
             options.  Additionally, any timeouts specified with the -w option
             are ignored.

Comment: The version is written in the very first line of help output: *nc -h*.

Comment: OpenBSD netcat (Debian patchlevel 1.89-3ubuntu2)

Comment: A posted a new answer because the previous one is also valid to your question. In the end, you gonna use both. ;)

Comment: Bingo! now it works ! 
ubuntu@ubuntu-laptop:~$ nc -h
[v1.10-38]
Many Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome bro. Glad to help.